# Add a new "addopts" by default in pytest plugin?

Tags: pytest

I want to disable capture by default in a pytest plugin I'm working on. This can be done using an "ini" file normally as below:

```
[pytest]
addopts = -s
```

In the pytest docs they discuss "addini", and this works for other values I've tried but not addopts.

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.Parser.addini

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption

An alternative way to approach is to override the argument directly like so:

```py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--capture",
        dest="capture",
        help="Capture the output",
        default='no'
    )
```

...but this complains that there is an argument conflict with the existing capture argument.

Is there some other better practice for default values of addopts that I haven't thought of?